# How to set vim keymappings?

Tags: vimrc

I am tryng to use https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors,

```
" Default mapping
let g:multi_cursor_start_word_key      = '<C-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_select_all_word_key = '<A-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_start_key           = 'g<C-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_select_all_key      = 'g<A-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_next_key            = '<C-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_prev_key            = '<C-p>'
let g:multi_cursor_skip_key            = '<C-x>'
let g:multi_cursor_quit_key            = '<Esc>'
```

What does each of these mean? I presses Ctrl + n, and nothing gets selected. What am I missing?

Comment: The start key is `g<c-n>`, maybe start there?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble whats g?

Comment: Im just reading the code you posted—`start key = 'g<C-n>'`—press g and then control-n. And maybe read the plugins docs.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble https://github.com/amix/vimrc, so totally new to vim config, how do i use the multi cursor fn?

Comment: Yeah, i wouldnt go using someone else’s vim configuration if you’re new to vim configuration—you can learn by reading them, but you’ve got to understand them